# How do I list terms of a custom taxonomy at i.e. domain.com/brands/

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, taxonomy

I have a custom post type 'products' with custom taxonomy 'brands'.  My URL structure should be:

- domain.com/brands - should list the brands
- domain.com/brands/brand/ - should list products of the selected brand
- domain.com/brands/brand/product/ - should show the selected product

How do I define the URL rewrite of the CPT / taxonomy for this to work, and what template file lists the terms of the brand taxonomy, instead of listing posts?

Comment: At least the first part can be done with my answer here: 

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89535/redirect-taxonomy-to-custom-template-to-list-terms-in-taxonomy/89745#89745