# Redirect taxonomy to custom template to list terms in taxonomy

Tags: rewrite-rules, rewrite-tag

I'm trying to adapt some code on [calling a custom template via rewrite rule](http://www.ringabell.org/en/appeller-un-fichier-de-template-custom-avec-une-rewrite-rule-dans-wordpress/).

I have a custom taxonomy called "state".  I want to create an archive for the taxonomy, that lists all the *terms* in that taxonomy.

`http://www.site.com/state`

Would load my custom template where I can query the terms and loop through them.

Alabama
Alaska
Arizone
Arkinsas, etc

I know there is a possibility of some conflict if I had a page named "state" too, but that's a risk I can take.

The code in the tutorial works really well for

`http://www.site.com/state/1` or `http://www.site.com/state/2` but returns a 404 if there is no number captured.

and that number would be good for pagination if the terms list gets out of control.

Here's the code:

```
add_action('admin_init', 'handle_taxonomy_route');
function handle_taxonomy_route()
{
    add_rewrite_rule('^state/([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?state_var=$matches[1]', 'top');
}

add_filter('init', 'declare_vars');
function declare_vars()
{
    add_rewrite_tag('%state_var%', '([^&]+)');
}

add_filter('template_include', 'my_template', 1, 1);
function my_template($template)
{
    global $wp_query;

    if (isset($wp_query->query_vars['state_var'])) {
        return dirname(__FILE__) . '/state-list.php';
    }
    return $template;
}
```

From what I have tried so far, it doesn't appear to conflict with

`http://www.site.com/state/alabama`

Where Alabama is a term in the state taxonomy, but it should definitely only capture numbers.

A similar question went unanswered last year. [How do I list terms of a custom taxonomy at i.e. domain.com/brands/](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63220/how-do-i-list-terms-of-a-custom-taxonomy-at-i-e-domain-com-brands)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed a better rewrite rule for proper pagination.

```
function kia_custom_rewrite() {

    // registers the state_var query variable
    add_rewrite_tag('%state_var%','([^&]+)');

    // handles site.com/state and pagination such as site.com/state/page/2
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'state(/page/([0-9]+)?)?/?$',
        'index.php?state_var=all&paged=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );

}
// refresh/flush permalinks in the dashboard if this is changed in any way
add_action( 'init', 'kia_custom_rewrite', 99 );
```

The rewrite rule adds the query_var to check for here:

```
/*
 * Load custom templates
 * 1. Get a custom template for the /state "page"
 * 2. Get a custom template for the /state/some-state term
 */
function kia_template( $template ){
    global $wp_query;


    if ( 'all' == get_query_var('state_var') ) {
        $template = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/taxonomy-state-list.php';
    } 

    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'template_include', 'kia_template' );
```

Answer (score 0):

The 404 might be created because your regular expression requires the value after 'state/'. Please try to replace:

```
function handle_taxonomy_route()
{
    add_rewrite_rule('^state/([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?state_var=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
```

with:

```
function handle_taxonomy_route()
{
    add_rewrite_rule('^state/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?state_var=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to make a difference. `state_var` is not added so the `template_include` function isn't finding it. I did a `var_dump($wp_query)` and it looks like I might be able to make it work with the `pagename` parameter. WordPress is looking at my URL like it thinks it is a page.